# What Forex Services support the ForexConnect API?

Tags: programming, trading, algorithmic-trading, fx

I need API access to get ForEx tickers and order books for currency pairs. From what I can tell there is a .Net API called [ForexConnect](http://www.dailyfx.com/forex_forum/forexconnect/) which I can use to get this data. Now where can I get this data from? What services support this interface?

Comment: The example code that comes with the .Net ForexConnect API seems to show a connection to http://www.fxcorporate.com/Hosts.jsp - what is this? Is this a real service endpoint?

Comment: Why do you need that particular interface? Lots of market data comes through in a binary protocol, so you could just write your own feed handler.

Answer (score 1):

ForexConnect is an API for [FXCM](http://fxcm.com).

More information can be found in this PDF:

https://files.fxcorporate.com/api/Getting%20Started.pdf

Answer (score 0):

ForexConnect is an API used by the FXCM broker. You can open a demo account there to connect to.